# can Sharepoint asynchronous event receiver throw JS popup?

Tags: sharepoint, asynchronous, event-handling

I have ItemAdded event receiver which I want to throw JS alert (for simplicity, actually SP.UI.Status.addStatus) when it finished its work. As ItemAdded is asynchronous it runs in separate thread and does not interact with current context.
what are solutions besides using ItemAdding (synchronous ER) ?